# Where is WebSQL database folder in Web Inspector when debugging iOS app

Tags: ios, safari, web-sql

I have an app using WebSQL database. I can debug database when running app on my computer in Chrome. But when I try to debug it on my iPod (hooked up to my computer, using Safari's Web Inspector) there is no WebSQL folder under `Resources`. There are only `Local Storage` and `Session Storage`. Where did the `WebSQL database` folder go?
I'm using OS X 10.9.5, Safari 7.1, iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you've opened the storage tab, try hitting the refresh button (just above the network tab for me).